# Accessing AWS Lambda Context from Spring Cloud Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-cloud

I'm using Spring Cloud Function 1.0.0.RELEASE and the corresponding AWS adapter to run it in AWS lambda. Is there any way to retrieve the lambda function context from the Spring application context?

I know if you implement the RequestHandler interface yourself, then you get the Context object  as the second parameter of the handleRequest method (see below), but since the SpringBootRequestHandler is handling this, it's not clear to me how to access the  Context object. Any ideas?

Example of implementing RequestHandler directly

```
public class LambdaRequestHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
        return "Hello World - " + input;
    }
}
```

Deferring the implementation of RequestHandler to SpringBootRequestHandler

```
public class SomeFunctionHandler 
      extends SpringBootRequestHandler<SomeRequest, SomeResponse> {
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`SomeFunctionHandler` extends the `SpringBootRequestHandler`, so it can override the `handleRequest` method to get access to the AWS lambda `Context` object.

```
public class SomeFunctionHandler extends SpringBootRequestHandler<SomeRequest, SomeResponse> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeFunctionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public Object handleRequest(SomeRequest event, Context context) {
        logger.info("ARN=" + context.getInvokedFunctionArn());
        return super.handleRequest(event, context);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws` only, `@Autowired` might not work.

However, you could wrap your input with `org.springframework.messaging.Message`.

```java
public class FooHandler implements Function<Message<DynamodbEvent>, String> {

  @Override
  public String apply(Message<DynamodbEvent> message) {
    // Get AWS Lambda Context
    Context context = message.getHeaders().get("aws-context", Context.class);
    assert context != null;
    
    // Get the original input
    DynamodbEvent payload = message.getPayload();
    return payload.toString();
  }
}
```

Source:

- [FunctionInvoker#handleRequest](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/main/spring-cloud-function-adapters/spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/adapter/aws/FunctionInvoker.java#L109-L110)
- [AWSLambdaUtils#generateMessage](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/main/spring-cloud-function-adapters/spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/adapter/aws/AWSLambdaUtils.java#L138)

Answer (score 1):

In case you are exposing `Function` as a bean, you can simply `Autowire` the `Context` object.

Example:

```java
    @Autowired
    private Context context;

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
        logger.info("ARN=" + context.getInvokedFunctionArn());
        return value -> {
            if (value.equals("exception")) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Intentional exception which should result in HTTP 417");
            }
            else {
                return value.toUpperCase();
            }
        };
    }
```

Source : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68522189/1776132) answer.