# Java AWS Lambda - Avoid passing context too far down tree of calls

Tags: java, aws-lambda, lambda, dependency-injection, dagger

I used Dagger to inject dependencies on a Java Lambda:

```
public class LambdaEntryPointHandler implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, SQSBatchResponse> {
    private final Handler handler;

    public LambdaEntryPointHandler() {
        ServiceComponent component =  DaggerServiceComponent.create();
        handler = component.getRequestHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public SQSBatchResponse handleRequest(final SQSEvent sqsEvent, final Context context) {
        return handler.handleRequest(sqsEvent, context);
    }
}
```

I need to access the `awsRequestId` of the context in a call far down the chain of calls, it's really tedious to pass the context object as a parameter to all the caller functions. I was wondering if using Dagger I could inject the context as a dependency to that class that uses it, instead of passing the parameter.

I'm open to other suggestions, is there a global store available in this case? (Something like redux in react, to avoid passing props down the component tree)

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68522189/7662716), but I don't use Spring.